# viterbi decoder GPU

Tags: matlab, gpgpu, decoding, convolution

I have been working on porting Viterbi Most Likelyhood Decoding problem for some time now. While searching I came to know that, MATLAB provides a GPU accelerated Viterbi Decoder simulation using their Communication Toolbox.

I do not have access to MATLAB, and I could not find any papers describing the speed-ups they acheived using GPU accelerated MATLAB code. Can someone point out some resources where I can get some benchmarks to compare my implementation with?

Comment: I've access to GPU-acceleratd MATLAB. If you can provide some samples of running Viterbi Most Likelyhood Decoding on CPU in MATLAB, I can take the runs and report the comparison.

Comment: Yes, post your code and we can help (I'm with AccelerEyes).

Comment: I have been mostly interested in running the decoder at code rate 1/2 and constraint lengths 5 & 7, as they appear to be most suitable for my GPU. It would be very nice, if you can share the throughput acheived for these configuration. As of now i have been able to acheive 120-150Mbps throughtput using my AMD card. But still working on finetuning it. I am not allowed to share the code as it is propriatary. If you guys can point me to some paper discussing strategies that can be used to parallely decompose this problem, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Apparently, the Matlab code doesn't run that quickly, if it takes 6 years to complete. ;)